# AdBlock blocking my jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-analytics

Hi I am using uBlock Origin and it seems to be blocking this code I use for a div. I'm using a GA experiment to change the style of a div by the users variation.

```
<script>
    if ($(window).width() > 768 && $('.book-now').length) {
        // Ask Google Analytics which variation to show the user.
        var chosenVariation = cxApi.chooseVariation();

        // Define JavaScript for each page variation of this experiment.
        var pageVariations = [
            function () {
                $('.menu').addClass('menu-widget');
            },
            function () {
                $('.menu').addClass('menu-custom');
            }
        ];

        // Wait for the DOM to load, then execute the view for the chosen variation.
        $(document).ready(
            // Execute the chosen view
            pageVariations[chosenVariation]
        );
    }
</script>



<!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
<script>

    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-46138466-1', 'thehoxton.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');



</script>
```

Does AdBlock/uBlock block Google Analytics code or is there something with my JavaScript that allows it to be blocked by theres plugins?

Answer (score 0):

ABP does indeed block GA. Not sure about uBlock.

There is a mock-up to work around ABP [here](http://kennystechtalk.blogspot.com/2016/03/adblockanalytics.html).